# VS2010 and Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1

I've been developing with VB 2010 and Windows 7 for years.

Are there any "issues" I should be aware off when migrating VB2010 over to Windows 8.1

Any advice will be much appreciated.

John

Comment: I doubt it but I can't say definitively. If there was a problem there would be KB articles and horror stories posted on blogs, so if none of those come up from a search you're probably OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used visual studio 2010 on windows 8.1 and windows 10 so far I did not have any issues working on both the OS.

I am using visual studio 2010 professional with sp1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the latest service packs and hotfixes to be fully compatible with Windows 8 and above:

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
3. [Visual Studio 2010 GDR for Team Foundation Service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)
4. [Visual Studio 2010 Compatibility Update for Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677)

You will need to upgrade your Visual Studio version to 2013 in order to build Windows 8 and 8.1 apps, but as long as you're targeting a Desktop application, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Me too have been using the VS 2010 Professional on windows 7 and I migrated to Windows 8.1.
Usually I develop console apps, desktop apps and I mostly use Access Databases as the database for my programs..
And also I use C# and VB..
So far I havent had any issue with VS2010 on windows 8.1.
That is my experience about that and I hope this will be a help for you.. :)

Thanks